# How do I add a "total_num" field by aggregating equal values with SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Well, I apologize for the horrible question title. I am not a SQL or database guy so I find I am somewhat lacking the vocabulary to succinctly describe what I am trying to do. So, I will just pose the question as an anecdote.

I have two tables:

```
+-------+--------+------------+
| STATE | REGION |  CAPITAL   |
+-------+--------+------------+
| WA    | X      | Olympia    |
| CA    | IX     | Sacramento |
| TX    | VI     | Austin     |
+-------+--------+------------+
```

And:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| NAME  | NUMBER | STATE |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Tom   |      1 | WA    |
| Dick  |      5 | WA    |
| Larry |     45 | WA    |
| Joe   |     65 | TX    |
| John  |      3 | CA    |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

How can I then query the second table so that I can "append" a fourth field to the first table that stores a total count for the number of people in that state, such that the first table would then look like this:

```
+-------+--------+------------+-------+
| STATE | REGION |  CAPITAL   | COUNT |
+-------+--------+------------+-------+
| WA    | X      | Olympia    |     3 |
| CA    | IX     | Sacramento |     1 |
| TX    | VI     | Austin     |     1 |
+-------+--------+------------+-------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Homework?  Sounds like you want to look up `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

Comment: I promise this is not a homework problem! Or are you giving me homework? If that is the case then I actually appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.STATE, s.REGION, s.CAPITAL, COUNT(*) as 'COUNT'
FROM secondtable s
JOIN firsttable f ON s.STATE = f.STATE
GROUP BY f.STATE, f.REGION, f.CAPITAL
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select sc.state,sc.region.sc.capital, count(*) as tot
from State_City_Table sc
join people_table pt on pt.state=sc.state
group by sc.state,sc.region.sc.capital
```

Comment: Why do you assume it is homework for a 29 year old guy who has been on Stack Overflow for over a year? If a homework tag is on a question, I will not answer it unless I see what has been attempted so far...

Comment: +1 from me to offset the -1 by someone else. :P  (Some people are sooo touchy.)

Comment: Thanks :), not necessary, but appreciated

Comment: How is there any indication that this is homework??  A downvote is a bit uncalled for I think.

Comment: Guys, this is not homework... I don't know how to reassure someone over the internet but, well, it isn't.

Comment: Well, you've been on Stack Overflow for almost two years, you are listed as 29 years old, and you didn't tag it as homework.   That is good enough for me...

Comment: would be nice to see the energy used talking about GROUP BY and COUNT too no? I'd be happy to reverse if I did.